# PHP - Variable processed and return a value

Tags: php

I need to process a variable through some validation to return a value of which I can use later on in my script. My $var is coming from a GET.

Example: A variable may come through like below.

```
$var = 'main server app1 stop'
```

I need to break up the string as follows.

`main server` needs to look up a list like below and return the ip address.

```
192.168.10.1 = 'main server' 
192.168.10.2 = 'backup server'
```

`app1` also needs to be looked up in a list and return the match.

```
service httpd = 'app1' 
service iptables = 'app2'
```

Then bring back the relevant matches together. In this example I would want the following returned.

```
192.168.10.1 service httpd stop
```

I hope I have explained this clear enough. If not tell me what I need to detail more.

Thanks!

Comment: Consider reading about `explode` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to convert a string to an array - it's simpler to irritate an array than a string in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PLEASE, PLEASE read more about [explode()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp) and arrays in PHP but here's the cheese:

```
$var = 'main server app1 stop';

$server = array(
    'main server'   => '192.168.10.1',
    'backup server' => '192.168.10.2',
);

$service = array(
    'app1' => 'service httpd',
    'app2' => 'service iptables',
);

$arr = explode(' ', $var);

echo $server["$arr[0] $arr[1]"] . ' ' . $service[$arr[2]] . ' ' . $arr[3];
```

output:

```
192.168.10.1 service httpd stop
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing the following

```
$server = (strpos($var,'main') !== false) ? '192.168.10.1' 
                                          : '192.168.10.2' ;

$service = (strpos($var,'app1') !== false) ? 'httpd' : 'iptables';
$output = $server . ' service ' . $service . ' stop';
```

Comment: Would this only work with 2 values in the list? As I have now added multiple items in the lists.

Comment: if you'll have more values then @Ceeee's solution is more preferable